# Implementing filters using check boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to filter the content in the gridview based on the checkboxes that I have selected. The checkboxes are outside of the gridview. This is something similar to Amazon website where we can filter our items search based on the price range selected, or model selected in the left bar. Can anyone suggest me how to approach. I am doing this project in c#

I have tried something like this.

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;padding;margin:0px">
 <li> $240 -$650<input type="checkbox" id="test" class="cb" /></li>
<li>$650- $1200<input type="checkbox" id="test1" class="cb"/> </li>
</ul>

<asp:GridView id="gdv1">Example</<asp:GridView>
<asp:GridView id="gdv1">Example1</<asp:GridView>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cb").change(function() {    
    $("#" + this.id.replace('test', 'example')).toggle(this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

but the problem is I have to bind all the gridviews beforehand and have only the option of hiding and showing. Instead I want to dynamically compute what the user has filtered and then display in the gridview.  Any thoughts. Thank again.

Comment: Mathias I have just edited my question. Can you please go through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to check in the page onload event if the request form contains the keys related to your search panel fields, then you have to compose the where clause to retrieve filtered data, then bind data to gridview